# Editing and saving a text file always shows Save As dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I've been wanting to use Visual Studio 2013 Preview for editing some simple Python scripts. I open the script, edit as usual. But when I hit 'ctrl-s', Visual Studio 2013 Preview takes me to a 'Save As' dialog.

The file name hasn't changed, and the file path is right, so it's not damaging.

How can this be solved to allow me to save as I expect?

Comment: Are you running Resharper 8? I've seen this issue with R8 but wanted to know if its VS2013 or Resharper which is the problem

Comment: @Dr.ABT I opened a support ticket with Microsoft. I'm also using Resharper 8 but I think the issue is with Visual Studio. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/798820/saving-text-files-sometimes-opens-the-save-as-dialog

Comment: Good work, let me know if you get a response! This issue is affecting our whole team ...

Comment: @Dr.ABT Received a response. They said the issue is fixed and the patch will be released in a future update.

Comment: Boom. Thanks - appreciate it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try running VS as admin or change the permissions of the file (right click on it and click properties ) and see if it's marked as read only.

Comment: Thanks, running as admin fixes the issue.

Comment: "Run as Admin" doesn't work for me. Whenever I press and hold Ctrl + S, it popup SaveAs dialog. 

If I press (quickly) Ctrl+S then the dialog won't show. It only appears when I press and hold.

Note: I'm also using Resharper8 with VS2013.

Comment: @DioPhung Refer to my comments above. This is a known issue and a patch is on its way.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2012 exhibits the same behaviour if a file is opened for reading.

You can verify this using the [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) utility from SysInternals.

```
[16:52:37] C:\windows\system32>
$  handle filepath

Handle v3.51
Copyright (C) 1997-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

iisexpress.exe     pid: 8896   type: File           D04: C:\Projects\filepath.js
```

The following snippet was causing this:

```
var hash = Convert.ToBase64String(new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(IO.File.OpenRead(filePath)));
```

Properly closing the stream when done fixed it:

```
string hash = null;
using (fileStream == File.OpenRead(filePath)) {
    hash = Convert.ToBase64String(new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(fileStream));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue because there was no space on the disc. VS started working fine once i cleared some space.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with trying to save a css file (a SASS .scss file). I tried to run as admin and also checked the file to make sure it was not read-only, and also closed all other related processes (it was an SASS file that was being watched by gulp). It still did not allow me to save normally, and when I tried to save via the Save As dialog box, it said it was locked by another process. I then went to restart my VM, and was told by Windows 10 that there were pending updates. I applied the updates and restarted, and the problem went away. My guess is that in my case, the pending updates had locked things up, explaining why I could no longer save.